# ASP.NET MVC5 each Razor Page very slow on first load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is not the same delay experiences when the *first request* arrives, but this is a delay that is experienced each time a Razor based view is accessed for the first time, it can take a second or two. All subsequent requests to that view are very fast.  This happens even for simple views that are not doing any kind of programmatic work (such as accessing a database etc).

I've already ensured that `debug=false` in the compilation tag under system.web in the config file.

I've also removed set Razor as the only view-engine via the `Global.asax`

**What could be causing this delay?**  This seems like a problem experienced in the old asp.net 'website' days before it moved to a 'web application' where each .aspx.cs codebehind was compiled at deployment rather than at runtime.  Does Razor still suffer from this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The issue is caused by the parsing and compilation of the Razor views. Once views are compiled, they execute very quickly. Views are only parsed and compiled on the first request for the view, or if the view has been modified since the last compile.

You can resolve this on a deployed WebApp by precompling your views as a part of your Publish process. See the image below on how to do it in VS2012, using the standard publish dialog.

You can select the updatable option if you wish, but for a production site I wouldn't recommend it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - seems obvious now. I have tried this and seems to have made a dramatic improvement, there is still a lag but nothing compared to the previous delay. It also exposes a bug in VS2013 where it runs a 32-bit compiler rather than the 64-bit one required, once I got around that it works.

Comment: This made no difference to my site. Each page still loading very slowly.

Comment: @user2444499 the "Allow precompiled site to be updatable" setting must be set to OFF for views to precompile. It is set on by default,

Comment: @Ryan It doesn't work, no matter what. I can see compiled view dlls in bin, but initial renderings still taking as long as before. Running VS2013, compiling as 64bit.

Comment: The thing that worked for me was removing System.Web.Optimization and WebGrease.  This entails also ripping out all of the Bundling components for your css and scripts, but holy moly do pages load faster, they are pretty much instant.  It's too bad that these NuGet packages are included by default.

Comment: this solution improves around 70% of loading the views on the first load.

Comment: @Ryan is correct. I unchecked `Allow precompiled site to be updatable` and viola, it worked so much better, even on dev!

Answer (score 5):

Webgrease. It minifies your production js and css bundles on first load, then caches them. Problem is that when the minification has errors it will try to compile every time, running whatever error routines are in there.
There is no bug report and the only way of finding out this is happening is by directly opening the references and seeing stuff like:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(69,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@import'
(69,9): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '"variables.less"'
(70,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@import'
```

Which (in the above case) reveals that your unnecessary .less or .sass files have been published - which is usually the result of wildcard bundling.
Wildcard bundling will cost you more time than it saves.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing views can be slow. Have you tried using `RazorGenerator` to compile your views?

Type `install-package RazorGenerator` in the NuGet Package Manager Console, or install it via NuGet manually [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Mvc/).