# MVC return PartialView slow first time after edit

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I imagine the answer to this is something cache related, but to better understand the reason I thought I'd at least ask.

In my MVC project I'm doing an AJAX request to the controller to return a html page as a partial view, I then inject that html into the page with. The reason for this is the model for the view changes depending on what's clicked.

Here is the AJAX: (Please note all code has been modified for simplicity)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "../../Home/NewMembershipAlloc/",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#partial_div').html(data);
    }
});
```

Here is the controller method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> NewMembershipAlloc()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Popup/GenericPopup.cshtml", new Membership());
}
```

Now, just to be clear, this all works as intended. Nearly everytime I run this code it takes maybe 20ms, as shown below: 
[image]

**However**, if I edit my html page in any way, even if I just remove one character and then add it back in. The next time I perform the request it will take 2 seconds (ish).

[image]

So this is happening within my development environment which should be the only place my html is edited. It **does not** happen when I refresh the page, clear the cache or open a new browser. So my questions are the following:

1. What's the full reason this is happening?
2. Can I stop it from being slow the first time? Or is it the price I pay for loading new html?
3. Would this delay ever happen after release? If someone doesn't use the webpage for a few days for example and shuts down their machine maybe.

Answer (score 2):

It looks similar to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25006809/6862867

In reference to the above link:

The first time a new or edited view is requested the server will parse and compile the code. This takes a small amount of time (but longer than you'd expect for a page load) and is only required once each time the page changes. I suspect that the reason you are seeing it even if you remove a character and then add it back in is that the server does not recognise what has changed until parse/compile time only that the file has changed since the last time it was loaded.

It would seem that you can precompile your project on publish although I'm not clear myself on how this is done/works.

Post release it would happen only the very first time that page was loaded. You could get round this by making that request yourself as soon as you release it.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17107393)

Comment: My Apologies, I thought it did answer the question as the question asks why it takes so much longer the first time an edited view takes longer to load and the question I referenced explains that it is due to the page being compiled the first time it is requested. I appreciate the time taken to respond but I am unclear why it is an incorrect answer. Should I have summarised the linked answer within my answer? I am trying to be more useful in this community and would appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Edited my answer to be more helpful (hopefully)